# Button action issue in xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using xcode 4.6 and i have set iOS deployment target to 4.3. When I build and run in iOS simulator 6.1, i was able to navigate to next viewController. But, when I build and run for iOS 5.0 or 5.1, nothing happens on button click. Does anyone have solution to this? Can't see any bug in my code. Is it a common issue?

I have used

```
 NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];

if([self.emailTextField.text isEqualToString:@""] && [self.phoneNumberTextField.text isEqualToString:@""])
{
    UIAlertView *view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can't login" message:@"Email id as well as phone number is missing. Please mention atleast one info." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [view show];
}
else if([emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailTextField.text] == NO)
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Can't login" message:@"Please enter a valid email id" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alertView show];
}

else
{
    UIViewController *profileVc = [[ProfileViewController alloc]init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profileVc animated:YES];
    //[self presentViewController:profileVc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

in `IBAction`

Comment: plz..display..yr code of btnAction

Comment: @deepak thakur add some code of your button.

Comment: have you use any Gesture in view???

Comment: yes Viuss mca.. gesture is there in the view

Comment: gesture is there from next view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using gesture recognizer then set this
|

```
buttonGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Then you will be able to get your button action.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have to deselect Canceled in View option from Xib show in below image [image]

or You can set `cancelsTouchesInView = NO` to your gesture property.